# how to create template pipeline in jenkins

Tags: templates, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create template Pipeline for use many pipeline jobs.
When i search i don`t know "Select Job Template"  Because when i click Create new job and that page have no template job item to choice. I already install all plugin saw at many tutorial.
May be thats question is very simple but i am new learn to jenkins.
I hope someone help me...
Thanks alot

[image]

Jenkins Templating Engine also installed. After choice Pipeline at new job and show below page.

[image]

Can i continue with thats or not How can i start?
If have tutorial for Pipeline templates please can u tell me..
i really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

First 3 [hits from Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jenkins%20Pipeline%20template) :

- Jenkins Blog: [Introducing the Jenkins Templating Engine!](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/05/09/templating-engine/#introducing-the-jenkins-templating-engine)
- CloudBees: [Setting up a Pipeline Template](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipeline-templates-user-guide/setting-up-a-pipeline-template)
- CD Foundation: [Jenkins Templating Engine: How To Build Reusable Pipeline Templates](https://cd.foundation/blog/2020/08/05/jenkins-templating-engine-how-to-build-reusable-pipeline-templates/) (with video!)

Answer (score 0):

would recommend checking out this introductory JTE video: [CDF MeetUp - Jenkins Templating Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYLaoqn0pDE)

There are also [Learning Labs](https://boozallen.github.io/sdp-docs/learning-labs/1/index.html) in the JTE docs.